# issues regarding deploying spring -hibernate application in jboss

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I have a web application developed in spring-hibernate. it is running fine in tomcat. but when I am trying to deploy it in jboss-7.0.0.CR1 server it's throwing exceptions. do I need to do any special configuration for jboss.

here is the server log

```
12:06:08,153 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
12:06:08,157 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
12:06:08,158 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
12:06:08,160 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
12:06:08,485 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
12:06:08,493 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12:06:08,929 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed

12:06:08,931 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

12:06:08,934 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)

12:06:08,934 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)

12:06:08,935 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)

12:06:08,935 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)

12:06:08,935 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)

12:06:08,935 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)

12:06:08,936 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)

12:06:08,936 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)

12:06:08,936 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)

12:06:08,936 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)

12:06:08,938 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)

12:06:08,938 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)

12:06:08,946 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)

12:06:08,946 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)

12:06:08,947 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)

12:06:08,955 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)

12:06:08,955 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)

12:06:08,955 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)

12:06:08,964 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)

12:06:08,964 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3631)

12:06:08,964 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3844)

12:06:08,972 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70)

12:06:08,972 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)

12:06:08,973 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)

12:06:08,981 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

12:06:08,981 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

12:06:08,982 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

12:06:08,982 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;

12:06:08,987 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881)

12:06:08,987 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795)

12:06:08,992 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)

12:06:08,992 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)

12:06:08,992 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)

12:06:08,997 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)

12:06:08,997 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)

12:06:08,998 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)

12:06:09,002 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)

12:06:09,002 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)

12:06:09,002 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)

12:06:09,007 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)

12:06:09,008 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)

12:06:09,012 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)

12:06:09,013 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-7)    ... 26 more

12:06:09,013 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/freight]] (MSC service thread 1-7) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3631) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3844) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.0.CR1.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    ... 26 more

12:06:09,095 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/freight]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Servlet /freight threw load() exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()Ljavax/persistence/ForeignKey;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindManyToOne(AnnotationBinder.java:2881) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1795) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3631) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3844) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.0.CR1.jar:7.0.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.8.0_31]

12:06:09,166 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-7) registering web context: /freight
12:06:09,171 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss AS 7.0.0.CR1 "White Rabbit" started in 6570ms - Started 778 of 837 services (59 services are passive or on-demand)
12:06:09,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployed "test.war"
12:06:09,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployed "freight.war"
```

Comment: Which version of JPA API are you using ? For some reason in JBOSS the older version is being picked up .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550463/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-joincolumn-foreignkey

Comment: I am not including any entry for jpa in pom. I am using jpa for validation using hibernate. below are my hibernate entries in pom.xml
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
 <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I have solved the issue. yes it was happening due to conflict in jar. in my application hibernate was using jpa2.1 while jboss7.0  comes with  jpa version 2.0. i replaced the jboss jar with my jpa version 2.1 jar which my application is using. this settles the issue. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Since you solved it .. You can answer your own question I think ..